# How to do scalar testing with android?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, unit-testing, testing

I'm not sure "scalar testing" is the correct term for it but I mean tests that aren't boolean "fail or succeed". The problem I'm working on is a chromatic tuner for android:

http://code.google.com/p/androidtuner/

And I want to test the algorithm by running a few wav files and processing the resulting pitch graph. The goal is to define the scalar test result as a normalized x-minus-y-squared-sum where x is the detected pitch and y is the expected pitch. So a perfect test run would be 0 but more realistically I'd like to tweak the algorithm and see if/how it improved on all the test cases.

Generally speaking - can a unit test result in a number and not a boolean? Does the android testing framework allow it? How should I integrate whichever solution with Eclipse?

My current idea is to just circumvent everything and use adb to fetch files generated after running each test. Though that's not too awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strikes me that a unit test is the wrong tool for the task you're tackling here. By their very nature, unit testing frameworks are designed to produce true/false results.

If all you're seeking to do is produce some metrics by test invoking your algorithm with different input data you might want to consider writing your own [`Instrumentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) subclass. This is what Android itself uses to run your unit tests on the device.

An `Instrumentation` will allow you to invoke your services/activities with whatever datasets you need and you can build up a results `Bundle` to summarise the results.

Plus you can invoke an instrumentation from the ADB, just like a set of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can make it with the new feautures of JUnit4.

Write a Rule that executes @Before and @After each time:
[JUnit Kungfu slide 34](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/09/30/junit-kung-fu-getting-more-out-your-unit-tests)

Write a Parameterized Test that calculates the result:
[JUnit Kungfu slide 23](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/09/30/junit-kung-fu-getting-more-out-your-unit-tests)

If you work with spreadsheet you can fill your spreadsheet with values like 
current-value;expected-min;expected-max

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    private final int current;


    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { -1 , -10, -6 },
            { -2 , -11, -7 },
            { -3 , -12, -8 },
            { -4 , -13, -9 },
            { -5 , -14, -10 }
        });
    }

    public ParameterizedTest(int current, int expectedMin, int expectedMax) {
        this.current = current;
        this.min = expectedMin;
        this.max = expectedMax;

    }


    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        int yourNewValue = YourNormalizer.normalize(current);
        assertThat(yourNewValue, both(greaterThan(min)).and(lessThanOrEqualTo(max)));
    }
}
```

I don't know any other way to test data. HF

Comment: That seems like a nice way to import data. But still the tests result in either success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing is not really suitable in this case. The result of a unit test is pass/fail, so you would need to set a threshold (error margin) that defines what is a pass. This does produce some results, i.e. you can compare the number of pass/fails between runs, but you also loose quite a bit of info in the process.

I'd suggest just logging the scalar results to a CSV file, and loading it later on a spreadsheet. You could even do it from within the unit tests.

Apart from this I can't think of a framework that does exactly what you need.